# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${status.index}"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

I couldn't figure out the root-cause of this issue, It was working fine with previous version of Spring i.e Spring 3.2.X but with the latest version i.e. Spring 4.1.0 it doesn't. Any idea what am I doing wrong.

### Controller:

```
  @ActionMapping(params = "action=view")
    public ModelAndView viewMessages(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse,    Model model,@ModelAttribute("message") Message message, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
            HttpServletRequest servletRequest = PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest);
            String sessionId = servletRequest.getSession().getId();           
            ArrayList<Message> messageList = getMessageList(sessionId);
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("list");
            modelAndView.addObject("message", new Message());
           modelAndView.addObject("messageList",messageList);
            return modelAndView;
 }
```

---

```
Form object:
    public class MessageForm implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();


    public ArrayList<Message> getMessageList() {
        return messageList;
    }

    public void setMessageList(ArrayList<Message> messageList) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Long(id).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (! (obj instanceof MessageForm)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.id == ((MessageForm)obj).getId();
    }
```

---

```
list.jsp:

<form:form method="post" commandName="messageForm">
<portlet:defineObjects/>
<br/>

<c:if test="${empty messageForm.messageList}">No Message(s) found.</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty messageForm.messageList}">
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" class="table table-striped table-borderless">
   <c:forEach items="${messageForm.messageList}" var="message" varStatus="status">
      <tr>          

        <td>
        <form:checkbox path='messageList[${status.index}].deleteFlag' value="${message.deleteFlag}"/>
        </td>
```

---

```
Error:
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'messageList[${status.index}]' of bean class [com.mtorg.messagecenter.domain.MessageForm]: Invalid index in property path 'messageList[${status.index}]'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${status.index}"
    at org.springframework.beans.mtorg.getPropertyValue(mtorg.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.mtorg.getNestedBeanWrapper(mtorg.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.mtorg.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(mtorg.java:528)
    at org.springframework.beans.mtorg.getPropertyValue(mtorg.java:694)
```

---

```
Jars:
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
iText-5.0.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
log4j.jar
spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
standard-1.1.2.jar
```

Comment: Could we see where you set the value of [${status.index} ?

Comment: Just to note that - this works perfectly with Spring v3.2.8, but with v4.1.0 only it throws this error, something got changed in later version, does it ring a bell?